# How can I compute rolling average on BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm facing an issue and I'm not sure how to compute it on Big Query, I have a table where I have the amount of bananas a user has eaten with a date associated when he ate some:

```
+------+-------+--------------+
| user | banana|    date      |
+------+-------+--------------+
| a    |     5 |  2019/01/18  |
| .    |     ..|              |
| a    |     2 |  2019/05/18  |
| b    |     2 |  2019/02/18  |
| b    |     3 |  2019/03/18  |
| b    |     1 |  2019/03/18  |
+------+-------+--------------+
```

I would like to get something like this :

```
+------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| user | date  T     |AVG1st week before T|AVG2nd   week before T|
+------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
| a    | 2019/01/18  |  2                 |           1          |
| .    |     ..      |  ..                |           .          |
| a    | 2019/01/20  |  3                 |           1          |
| b    |     2       |  2                 |          2.5         |
| b    |     3       |  2                 |           5          |
| b    |     1       |  1                 |           2          |
+------+-------------+--------------------+----------------------+
```

where " AVG 1st week before T" is the average of daily banana consumed during the 7 days before T for a user.

I thought that for each row I would compute both the "7 days before T" variable and create the "14 days before T" variable. Then calculate in a subquery the amount but I think it's not an optimal way to handle this.

if you have any advice I'll be glad to discuss about it!

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 4):

Something worthwhile to read [Analytic Functions Concepts in Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts)

Here is a snippet that I came up with, at the current row gives the 'average banana eaten' in the last 7 days.

```
SELECT
  user,
  banana,
  date,
  AVG(banana) OVER (ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS avg
FROM
  `banana.banana`
WHERE
  user = 'a'
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, First thank you for your answer, I appreciate. 

The thing is my data is sparse, there are dates which are missing, imagine a gap of a days of weeks between 2 dates, how to take into account that sparse part in the sql request ? 

After some search I found this : stackoverflow.com/questions/49883311/… 
But is doesn't work if the gap between 2 dates is bigger than the size of your window, in this specific case it will put the value of the last row instead of the average. 
If you know how to do it without using cartesian product I'd be glad to hear about it,
Thank you !